# Does not writing return statement in void function occupies the stack memory?

Tags: c, recursion, stack, quicksort, void

This is a simple recursive function of quicksort algorithm and I didn't find return statement in this function so will it not empty the stack after the last recursion?

```
void quicksort(int arr[], int p, int r){
    int q = partition(arr, p, r);
    if(p < r){
        quicksort(arr,p, q-1);
        quicksort(arr,q+1, r);
    }
}
```

This function has no return statemnt so will the recursive functions stay on the stack forever or will they ever get emptied?

Comment: The recursion will end when `p >= r`.

Comment: There is an implicit `return` statement just before the closing `}`. In general it is useful to bear in mind that tools (languages, compilers) that do stupid things tend to die off quickly.

Comment: it is a `void` function, so no return value is expected from it.  Also, normally is the caller code who cleans the stack and not the function code. Finally, there's always an implicit `return;` at the end of a `void` function.

Answer (score 4):

The stack frame for the function is cleared *when it eventually exits*.

An explicit `return` statement is not necessary for this to happen; when the program flow comes across the closing brace the function will exit anyway, and its stack frame will be cleared.

Another typical way a function can exit without `return` (albeit not in C) is by throwing an exception; again, the stack frame will be cleared.

Comment: I'd use the phrase "when it eventually *returns*" instead of "when it eventually *exits*" to ensure any future reader doesn't confuse a `return` statement with the `exit` call.

Comment: @AndrewHenle the funny thing is, I chose the word "exits" instead of "returns" specifically so as to avoid creating any ambiguousness with the `return` statement. :D

Comment: @AndrewHenle I think there's no confusion since he's referring to the function (*it*) and not to the process.

Comment: @Jon I was concerned that an inexperienced C coder unaware of the implicit `return` of a `void` function.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `return` statements in `void` functions are necessary only in situations when you want to return prior to reaching the end of the function's body. Last-line `return` statements are superfluous, and can be ignored. The stack will be cleaned with or without a `return`.

Answer (score 0):

> This function has no return statemnt so will the recursive functions
>   stay on the stack forever or will they ever get emptied?

In the case of void functions, when the code ends, it ends. Here, the void function will end when p >= r. The stack frame shall be removed when it ends.
The last closing curly brace '}' at the end of code is an implicit return statement and so a return will not be needed.

There is no requirement for an explicit 'return' at the end for void function. However you can use 'return' in void function if it should exit earlier on certain condition before reaching the end of function/code . You can also use 'return' at end of void function if you want to avoid ambiguity on where the function ended as a coding guideline/practice.